# Handling Backslash Escape Sequences in C

Tags: c, escaping, backslash, html-escape-characters

I was looking at an example in my course slides, which didn't come with much explanation.

```
char getchar_escaped(void)
{
   char c;
   if ((c = getchar()) != '\\') return c;

   switch ((c = getchar())) {
     case '\\':
       return '\\';
     case 'n':
       return '\n';
     default:
       return c;
   }
}
```

What exactly is happening in this code? How is this dealing with newlines and double slashes?

Comment: [Try explaining the code out loud for your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or suitable substitute, like a roommate, friend, significant other etc.).

Comment: The switch is wasteful — the `case '\\': return '\\';` is equivalent to what happens with `default:`, so you could have `if ((c = getchar()) == 'n') return '\n'; return c;` in place of the `switch`. Basically, if the input contains a backslash followed by an `n`, the function returns `'\n'` (newline); for any other backslash X sequence, it removes the leading backslash and returns the X. The code doesn't handle `EOF` properly. It should be `int c` (and the return type of the function should be `int` too); then the code will (mostly coincidentally) return EOF if one of the reads encounters EOF.

Answer (score 2):

In `C` character string literals and single-character constants, there are a number of 'special' characters that cannot be readily represented in source code text. Examples are the *newline* character, the *nul* (terminator) character and the *carriage-return*.

The language allows us coders to include such characters by using [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) - which are entered using the **backslash** character (`\`) followed by a suitably-descriptive 'ordinary' character. So, we can specify the *newline* character using an 'escaped' "n", like this: `char NewLine = '\n';` similarly, the *nul* and *carriage-return* characters are represented by `\0` and `\r`, respectively.

However, this convention causes a problem when we actually want to specify the *backslash* character itself! So, in order to do so, we specify an escape sequence where the second character is *also* a backslash; thus, the code `char BackSlash = '\\';` assigns to `BackSlash` the value (probably ASCII, but not necessarily so) of the backslash itself.

In your code, the test after the *first* `c = getchar()` checks for an input backslash character - which, if found, signals the start of one of these "escape sequences" - if it *isn't* found, we can simply return the actual character input. However, if we thus detect the start of an escape sequence, we need to check the next character: if this is an "n" (`case 'n':`) we return the escape sequence representing newline character (`return '\n';`); if it is *another* backslash (`case '\\':`) we return the sequence for the actual backslash (return '\';).

Other standard escape sequences aren't detected in your code, but it would be trivial to add further checks for these.

Please feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`\` has special meaning. It usually alter the meaning of the next character. Example: `\n` means new line, which is actually an ASCII character. But since `\` mean "alter the next character" than how you could have the literal `\` character? By altering it with `\` by doing `\\`. This mean "take the literal \ character".

```
char getchar_escaped(void)
{
   char c;
   // read a char from the input if it is the '\' character than return with it
   if ((c = getchar()) != '\\') return c; 
   switch ((c = getchar())) { // read in another character
   case '\\': return '\\'; // if it a '\' character then return '\'
   case 'n': return '\n'; // if it an 'n' than return the new line character: '\n'
   default: // otherwise
   return c; // just return the character that was read
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct uses of backslash escape sequences in the code you posted.

1. C uses backslash escape sequences as part of the grammar of the C language to represent certain character values in a character constant or a string literal. In a character constant or string literal, the sequence `\\` represents a single backslash character, and the sequence `\n` represents a single newline character. There are several more of these backslash escape sequences in the C language. Consult a C reference for details.
2. The program's `getchar_escaped` function is reading characters from standard input and applying its own backslash escape rules that happen to match those of the C language itself as far as the sequences `\\` and `\n` are concerned. If it is not currently reading a backslash escape sequence and it reads a backslash character, it reads the next character and returns a character corresponding to the backslash sequence (e.g. returning a newline character if the character following the backslash is `n`). (In fact, `n` is the only character that it doesn't map to an identical character. The special case for handling a backslash followed by a backslash is redundant.)