# How can i output "\" in console. C

Tags: c++, c, output

I want to write some symbols in the console, but I have troubles with the output of the `\` character.

I know it is reserved by C for formatting inside `printf()`, but I really want to output it.

```
printf(" __    __  __ __  ____    \n");
printf(" ||\  /||  || //  ||/\\   \n");
printf(" ||\\//||  ||//   ||\//  \n");
printf(" || \/ ||  ||\\   ||‾‾   \n");
printf(" ||    ||  || \\  ||   \n");
printf(" ‾‾
```

I expect that `\\` in this will just output like any other char, but it can't just output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Backslash Escape Sequences in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213633/handling-backslash-escape-sequences-in-c)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **try** the code, and then try to think about it logically. I bet you'll see that there **are** backslashes in the output - just that, where you want two of them, you get one instead. Does that give you a hint as to what you need to type in the code, in order to get an actual backslash in the string? Therefore, if you want two backslashes in the string, how many should you type in the code?

Comment: Since you tagged C++: `std::cout << "\\ hello \\\n";`

Comment: `cout` is not a "console".  The vast majority of terminal devices are not a "console".  If your terminal is running in a windowing environment, it (almost certainly) is not a "console".  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backspace is a special escape character in C/C++, so that you can type, e.g., `'\n'`. You can use `\\` to have a `\` in your string.

Comment: @BeaverWithKnife Glad I could help. If it works for you, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4):

In C you need to use `\\` in place of `\`:

```
puts(" __    __  __ __  ____    \n"
     " ||\\  /||  || //  ||/\\\\   \n"
     " ||\\\\//||  ||//   ||\\//   \n"
     " || \\/ ||  ||\\\\   ||‾‾    \n"
     " ||    ||  || \\\\  ||      \n");
```

In C++ you can use raw strings:

```
std::cout << R"(
__    __  __ __  ____
||\  /||  || //  ||/\\
||\\//||  ||//   ||\//
|| \/ ||  ||\\   ||‾‾ 
||    ||  || \\  ||   
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

escape it - for example

```
 printf(" ||    ||  || \\  ||   \n");
```

shpuld be

```
  printf(" ||    ||  || \\\\  ||   \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is indicating start of the *escape sequence in C & C++ languages.

```
    Escape sequence |   Hex value in ASCII  |   Character represented
    \a              |   07                  | Alert (Beep, Bell) (added in C89)[1]
    \b              |   08                  | Backspace
    \e              |   1B                  | Escape character
    \f              |   0C                  | Formfeed Page Break
    \n              |   0A                  | Newline (Line Feed); see notes below
    \r              |   0D                  | Carriage Return
    \t              |   09                  | Horizontal Tab
    \v              |   0B                  | Vertical Tab
    \\              |   5C                  | Backslash
    \'              |   27                  | Apostrophe or single quotation mark
    \"              |   22                  | Double quotation mark
    \?              |   3F                  | Question mark (used to avoid trigraphs)
    \nnn            |   any                 | The byte whose numerical value is given by nnn interpreted as an octal number
    \xhh…           |   any                 | The byte whose numerical value is given by hh… interpreted as a hexadecimal number
    \uhhhh          |   none                | Unicode code point below 10000 hexadecimal (added in C99)[1]: 26 
    \Uhhhhhhhh      |   none                | Unicode code point where h is a hexadecimal digit
```

*Table stolen from Wikipedia

As you see to get backslash you need to use `\\`